# How to create an 'andThen' as an infix operator for composability on a generic class in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, functional-programming

**Problem Statement:** I'm trying to recreate Scala/Finagle's `andThen` method chaining/composition across two types: Filters and Services.

The goal is to be able to do something like this:

```
val f1 = Filter1()
val f2 = Filter2()
val s3 = Service3()

val pipeline = f1 andThen f2 andThen s3 

val result = pipeline(4) //execute pipeline with integer value of 4
```

Filters should be combinable with other filters and also a service to "end a chain". Services should also be combinable with other services. Both seem to lead to `Unresolved reference andThen`

**Existing non-working solution:**

```
typealias Transformer<A,B> = (A) -> B

abstract class Service<A,B>: Transformer<A,B> {

    //DOESN'T WORK
    infix fun <A,B,C> Service<A,B>.andThen(f: Service<B,C>): Service<A,C> {
        val left = this
        return object : Service<A, C>() {
            override fun invoke(p1: A): C {
                return f(left.invoke(p1))
            }
        }
    }
}

typealias TwoWayTransformer<A,B,C,D> = (A, Service<C,D>) -> B

abstract class Filter<A,B,C,D>: TwoWayTransformer<A,B,C,D> {

    //DOESN'T WORK
    infix fun <A,B,E,F> Filter<A,B,C,D>.andThen(next: Filter<C,D,E,F>): Filter<A,B,E,F> {
        val left = this
        return object: Filter<A,B,E,F>() {
            override fun invoke(a: A, service: Service<E,F>): B {
                val s = object: Service<C,D>() {
                    override fun invoke(c: C): D { return next.invoke(c,service) }
                }

                return left.invoke(a,s)
            }
        }
    }

    //DOESN'T WORK
    infix fun <A,B,C,D> Filter<A,B,C,D>.andThen(next: Service<C,D>): Service<A,B> {
        val left = this
        return object: Service<A,B>() {
            override fun invoke(a: A): B {
                return left.invoke(a, next)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Sidebar:

`Filter<A,B,C,D>` can stitch with `Filter<C,D,E,F>` which can stitch with `Service<E,F>` - the last two types of the `left` must match with the first two of the `right` when doing `left andThen right`.

A `Filter<A,B,C,D>` is simply a function of type: `(A, Service<C,D>) -> E` which simplifies further to `(A, C->D) -> E`

Link to working fiddle with example services/filters: https://pl.kotl.in/yIx80SzDF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The signatures you need are

```
infix fun <C> andThen(f: Service<B,C>): Service<A,C>
infix fun <E,F> andThen(next: Filter<C,D,E,F>): Filter<A,B,E,F>
infix fun andThen(next: Service<C,D>): Service<A,B>
```

Never add any type variables to functions that are already declared in the definition of the class.  Never add an extra receiver for the class itself.

Comment: Aaah! I see. This is only m 10th day in Kotlin and am sorely missing a few things from my Scala days. I made the change and glad to report it worked. Thank you _/\\_